# Yammer App Development language

Tags: yammer

I want to develop a app for Yammer.

I currently have the web app as a external website written in PHP / JS and HTML.

Can i turn my external web-app into a yammer app, does it have to be written in ruby or can it be in PHP / HTML / JS/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just consume Yammer APIs then any language that has support for HTTP requests will likely work.

Yammer has a few official SDKs listed here:

https://developer.yammer.com/docs/js-sdk